# ¿Como calcular el porcentaje dentro de un array recorrido por una sentencia for?

Tags: c#, array

comunidad! ¿Que tal? El tema es que llevo un tiempo pensando e investigando pero no he podido dar con la solución, la situación es la siguiente:

```
for (int i = 0; i < getPalabras().lenghth; i++) {
     a = (100 / getPalabras().Length) * i;
     progreso(a);
}
```

`getPalabras()` es una función que me devuelve un array, el cual contiene un listado de palabras. Lo que busco hacer, es que dentro de este bucle se vaya registrando un progreso con la función `progreso()`.

Para 100 palabras entiendo que, expresado como está, debe funcionar. El problema es que la cantidad de palabras dentro del array es muy variada,

**¿Como debo calcular la variable `a`?**

No hace falta expresarlo exclusivamente en C# (Lenguaje en el que estoy trabajando), con que se entienda la idea agradecería mucho. ¡Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para calcular el **porcentaje** (sobre el total) que representa cada palabra al recorrer tu **array**, el código C# sería el siguiente:

```
        for (int i = 1; i <= getPalabras().Length; i++)
        {
            var a = (i * 100) / getPalabras().Length;
            // var resultado = "  Palabra " + i + "= " + a.ToString() + "%" + "</br>";
            // Response.Write(resultado);
            progreso(a);
        }
```

Para un ejemplo de un array de 15 palabras, el resultado sería algo así:

```
Palabra1 = 6%
Palabra2 = 13%
Palabra3 = 20%
Palabra4 = 26%
Palabra5 = 33%
Palabra6 = 40%
Palabra7 = 46%
Palabra8 = 53%
Palabra9 = 60%
Palabra10 = 66%
Palabra11 = 73%
Palabra12 = 80%
Palabra13 = 86%
Palabra14 = 93%
Palabra15 = 100%
```